# Can we add comments to an object using 'Alter type ' command

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Can we add comments to type object in Oracle 10g using 'Alter type ' command.?

Answer (score 1):

No. The syntax for ALTER TYPE is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_type.htm

Comments can be added to tables, columns, operators, indextypes, materialized views, and mining models.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01109

However, you can add PL/SQL comments to the type's member methods.